# How to design a UIActivity activityImage?

Tags: ios, uiactivity

I have searched the internet far and wide - there is plenty of stuff out there for what the code should be in the UIActivity subclass. This is not what I'm looking for.

I am not a designer. I am a developer who wants to create the actual image. The PNG. I have no idea how to do this, and Apple are very short on the details.

The only reason I'm taking this to SO is because there is no description on the type of PHG it should be in the Apple docs. I know how to export a PNG from Sketch or Photoshop as black & white. But this is one of those things that should take 15 minutes, but for whatever reason, every black & white icon I create, appears as a gray square in the share icon view.

NOTE: This is a relevant SO question because it's unique to the UIActivity framework.